# Can i restore before lase update in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: updates, fglrx

I have problem in my toshiba l500 when I work on ubuntu , first when I had ubuntu 10.04 , the shipset works all the time , then I resolved it was problems in graphical driver , now when I upgrade to 12.10 the same problem come again I repaired with other driver but at the last update the problem is back .what is the main raison for this problem and why just for toshiba , my friends havent this kind of problem .

Answer (score 0):

You laptop has ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 4530 graphics chip ([source](http://www.mytoshiba.com.au/products/computers/satellite/l500/psls3a-04m002/specifications))

In recent versions of their proprietary driver AMD removed support for Radeon 2xxx, 3xxx and 4xxx series. You need to use a "legacy" or open-source drivers.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/212280/14564) for more details